# Carroll's derivation of Hawking radiation

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, hawking-radiation, qft-in-curved-spacetime, unruh-effect

In Carroll's *Spacetime and Geometry: An Introduction to General Relativity*, in his derivation of Hawking radiation Carroll makes the following statement:

> "as observed over length and timescales set by $a_1^{-1} \ll 2GM$, spacetime looks essentially  flat"

which then enables him to invoke the Unruh effect on Minkowski space for a static accelerating observer very near the Schwarzschild event horizon, i.e. $r_1 -2GM  \ll 2GM$.

I didn't understand the meaning of this statement, which seems crucial for the derivation, and was wondering if someone could explain it further, perhaps with a little more mathematical formalism. A very similar statement is made in Jacobson's "Introductory lectures on Black Hole Thermodynamics."